# -nan(ind) в результате вычислений

Tags: c++, nan

У меня есть задача с некоторыми числовыми вычислениями и аппроксимацией дифф. уравнения, в частности используется такие библиотечные функции, как Zeroin, Rkf45, Spline, SEval и quanc8, написанные на C. Подключенные к проекту на C++ так:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "cmath.h"
};
```

При запуске программы массив выходных значений выдает -nan(ind). Однако в процессе лютой ярости программа была запущена несколько раз без каких-то изменений и в один из запусков массив результата выдал существующие значения.

В результате, каждые 10-15 запусков программа считает все правильно.
Понимаю, что вопрос без кода достаточно абстрактный, так что прикладываю ссылку с паролем на pastebin. Я знаю, что nan - это результат неверных вычислений, но почему после неоднократного перезапуска программа выдавала (и продолжает выдавать) верные математические результаты? С чем это может быть связано?

pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QvNkVbcz
password: 44yjWs7dDx

Comment: Как вариант - неинициализированные локальные переменные...

Comment: pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QvNkVbcz
password: 44yjWs7dDx

Comment: Тут надо весь код - включая эти ваши неизвестные `Forsythe.h` и `cmath.h` и реализации библиотеки... только никто его полностью ковырять не будет - долгая и неприятная задача. Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком (или хотя бы отладочным выводом) - это вам пригодится в любом случае, и смотрите, где и что не так. Ну нельзя повесить на кого-то отладку вашего проекта!

Comment: Я выложил именно мой код на случай, если существует какое-нибудь объяснение проблемы, к примеру, если человек с опытом разработки на плюсах посмотрит и увидит, что где-то, к примеру, деление на ноль или неинициализированные переменные, как вы сказали. Очевидно, никого отлаживать мой код я не заставляю.

Comment: Тем не менее, почему возникает nan я понимаю, я не понимаю почему периодически при запуске он не возникает. Если существует ответ на этот вопрос, я буду очень признателен!

Comment: Копать весь ваш код - слишком долго. Еще раз: обычно это - проблемы с памятью. Например, выход за границы массива (прочли какой-то мусор, или записали не туда), или неинициализированные локальные переменные (в которых содержится какой-то мусор). Это как спрашивать, почему у человека температура - вариантов может быть много.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно если вы пользуетесь Visual Studio, он выдает -nan(ind) когда что-то вышло за границы переменной которую вы используете.

Для примера можно взять факториал и если будет стоять тип int и Вы введете 20 то тоже напишет в результате -nan(ind).

Comment: NaN - только для типов с плавающей точкой, int им быть не может.

Comment: Странно, у меня когда-то выбивало -nan(ind) на факториале. Тогда спасибо за уточнение.